# Is there any SQL query to check if we are using a table or a column in any of our workflows (Sources or lookup)?

Tags: informatica-powercenter, teradatasql

I need to check impact of few of the columns/tables as some of the workflows are about to be decommissioned.

One way of finding is to manually open each session of each of the workflows and check in lookups/source queries.

So is there any easier way to do it ?

We are using Teradata SQL and Informatica 10.5.

Comment: DBQL has an "OBJECTS" option that could be activated to log table / column usage by Informatica username(s).

Comment: You can check the objects that use particular source and target that represent the underlying table.